# How to make a tight cell around text and expand empty ones?

Tags: html, css

I would like to build a `table` which has four columns: two with text and two empty. I want the empty ones to expand as much as possible and the ones with text to be tight.

The following snippet shows such a table: the widths of the columns are probably weighted with the size of the text inside.

```css
table,
td {
  border: solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table style="width: 100%">
  <tr>
    <td>This is some text</td>
    <td>And some more</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What could be done to turn this into a table like

[image]

where the text would be tightly surrounded by the cell and the empty ones expanded?

Comment: give 25% width for `td`?

Comment: @kukkuz: I do not know in advance how much text there will be. My last example unfortunately suggests a 25% width but if the texts were "hello" and "world" there would be more empty space for the last two columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a `flexbox` is an option, you can do this:

1. Give `display: flex` to the `tr`
2. Give `flex: 1` to the two empty ones.

See demo below:

```css
table,
td {
  border: solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table tr {
  display: flex;
}
td:nth-last-child(1),
td:nth-last-child(2) {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
      <td>This is some text. This is some text</td>
      <td>And some more</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: This is a great solution. I was not aware that one could use `flexbox` outside a `div` (but now that I think about it, there is no reason not to).

Answer (score 2):

If you know that the text will never need to wrap you can use some pseudo-element sorcery such as this. If the text might wrap the solution would probably be to set `display: inline-block` on `td:not(:empty)`, but then the borders would behave differently.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      table, td {
        border: solid;
        border-collapse: collapse;
      }

      td:not(:empty) {
        width: 1px;
        white-space: nowrap;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table style="width: 100%">
      <tr>
        <td>This is some text</td>
        <td>And some more</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```